# Custom Intent for Medical domain application

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

With release of iOS 10, SiriKit available for developers to make applications Siri enabled.But from [SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH11-SW1) Documentation, it looks like SiriKit supports for specific domain apps.

Currently Apple suggest following domains :

- VoIP calling
- Messaging
- Payments
- Photo
- Workouts
- Ride booking
- CarPlay(automotive vendors only)
- Restaurant reservations (requires
  additional support from Apple)

But my application is in medical domain, which is not listed above.
I want application to Siri enabled to book appointment with his/her favourite doctor, for possible time slots or find doctor according to location and book appointment.

Documented [Intent Domains](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/SiriDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH9-SW2).

So can we create custom `INIntent` to support this functionalities ?

Comment: Did you found any other way to accomplish this task? I'm creating an appointment app and I need the same feature you mentioned; maybe with List and Notes intent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't on iOS 10.
This is pure conjecture but creating a totally new intent probably requires much more work on Siri servers:

- necessary vocabulary for all the supported langugages
- mapping which parts of the spoken sentences should be part of Siri's vocabulary and which should be part of your apps
- developing the process/processes necessary to fulfill an intent (param resolving, confirmation etc.)

Comment: I am also thinking, this is not possible with available APIs. May be future release will help us. Thanks